# What is the brand of this shower tower panel?

Tags: bathroom, shower

I have this shower at home and I cannot identify the brand. Can anyone help with this. 2 of the LEDs are not working so need to get it fixed.

[image]

Comment: Where in the world are you located? That may help reduce the number of companies to search.

Comment: I am in NY. Sorry I missed that out. The LEDs and display have stopped working now. Can you repair these? I dont know which brand so can't even look for a manual

Answer (score 3):

This looks like an exact match, but I'm betting it is sold under a great number of "brands" as I can only find the maker on Amazon.

[AYDYA Detachable Rain Waterfall LED Shower Panel Wall Mounted with Digital Display](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C38VWRLV)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This varies in minor details, but I think it's in the same family.

[8-Jet Rainfall Shower Tower Shower Panel System with Rainfall Waterfall Shower Head and Shower Wand](https://www.homedepot.com/p/BWE-8-Jet-Rainfall-Shower-Tower-Shower-Panel-System-with-Rainfall-Waterfall-Shower-Head-and-Shower-Wand-in-chrome-Nickel-YTP07-BNC/326641483)

[image]